# Keyboard issues arising on orientation change

Tags: android, keyboard

In my app I am using various edit text and text view and list view.
Now my problem is **my keyboard appears again on orientation change**. Ideally when user minimize the keyboard, it should be in minimized state when device is tilted. But it reappears. How do we handle this situation.

My other problem is one of my edit text is some what at the end of screen. When keyboard appears, it hides the edit text. so user is not able to see what he is typing. What is the ideal way to handle this. 
thanks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Solution to all problem is this line android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustResize"

"stateUnchanged" will make the state of keyboard same as it was in earlier state. Either hidden or visible.

"adjustResize" will make your edit text visible.

Hope this helps.!!!

**Edit**

This need to be added in android manifest file.

Comment: We follow Single Activity Android Application based on Google's Recommendation. I have added onConfigChanges in the activity. In of my fragment, I am refreshing the entire fragment by attaching and detaching the fragment again. The above solution is not working for me in that particular fragment. Do you have any suggestion in this

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem. To keep the keyboard from re-appearing on rotation when you have TextViews, you must do 2 things-

1. Make sure the TextView doesn't have the focus. Even after hiding the keyboard, a TextView can still be focused. Try calling

   ```
   textView.clearFocus()
   ```

   and you should be able to see the difference in the TextView.
2. Make sure there is another view before it (like a parent LinearLayout, or even just a LinearLayout with 0 width and 0 height) which has these properties-

   ```
   android:focusable="true"
   android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this code in your Activities properties in the manifest

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

Like

```
 <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" >
```

This should take care of both your problems

Comment: Thanks Antrromet, but it will make my keyboard hidden always. and I don't want this. Thanks any ways.

Comment: It wont make it hidden always. It will just not open the keyboard when the activity is launched. If you click on the EditText then keyboard will be launched.

Answer (score 0):

For the Second Question :
You can set your layout to ScrollView to avoid hiding of edittext on Keyboard appears.
Put your entire layout in a ScrollView.

Comment: I was using scroll view but Black Devil answer was complete in itself. So thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following documentation to be helpful in understanding the various flags associated with the soft keyboard:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft