# Maintain keyboard state after device rotation

Tags: android, rotation, keyboard, fragment

I have a chat fragment with a listview and a edittext and i wanna when the user rotate the device, if the keyboard was shown, it still showing.
But on my fragment, if the user rotate from landscape to portrait and the keyboard is open, it reapear open. But from portrait to landscape, it closes on rotation.
I have no idea what could be and how could i save the keyboard state to recover it.
Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.example.irclient2.adapter.MyEditText
    android:id="@+id/chatinput"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionSend|flagNoExtractUi"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/chatlist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/chatinput"
    android:background="@drawable/fundo_chat"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="1.0sp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:scrollingCache="false"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    android:transcriptMode="normal" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: you can try to pass a boolean variable on your onSavedinstanceState bundle and show and hide keyboard programmatically

Comment: how to detect this boolean variable? can u post an example pls? i already tried something but unsuccessfull

Comment: Have you find Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Try removing/commenting any code you have in your fragment and activity that deals with handling focus and/or the keyboard (to isolate the problem) and try the solution to this question:

[Keyboard issues arising on orientation change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705366/keyboard-issues-arising-on-orientation-change)